# Image not loading on HTML page, showing as "?" in blue box in Safari

Tags: php, html, graph

I am attempting to create a Bar Graph using a php library that I found online.  I have copied the code from an example that I found on the library's website, but when I open the page the bar graph is being displayed as a "?" inside a blue box. I am fairly new to creating html pages with PHP.  I have the html file, and the graph.php file located in the same directory, and the phpgraphlib is located in a sub-directory of the same directory as the graph.php and html file.

Here is the code that I have been using for the html page:

```
<html>
<h3>This is where I want to display my graph</h3>
<img src="/Users/******/Desktop/Independent_Study/Pages/graph.php">
</html>
```

The ****** in the above file path is the name of the user on the computer.

Here is the code that I have been using for the php page:

```
<?php 

    include("/Users/******77/Desktop/Independent_Study/Pages/phpgraphlib-master/phpgraphlib.php");

    $graph = new PHPGraphLib(400,300);

    $data->array("Alex"=> 99);

    $graph->addData($data);
    $graph->setTitle("Test Scores");
    $graph->setTextColor("blue");
    $graph->createGraph();
?>
```

I got the PHPGraphLib from this website: http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/documentation/tutorial-setup-and-simple-example

How can I found out if the image thats being called by the html file is being created? Or is the problem related to the php code?

Comment: What does the browser show when you visit: `/Users/******/Desktop/Independent_Study/Pages/graph.php` directly

Comment: My money is on the fact that you don't have GD2 compiled into your PHP installation, and you have no error reporting enabled. What does `phpinfo();` have to say on the subject?

Comment: @Kypros when I visit that page directly the code for graph.php is pulled, and when I do the same thing for the phpgraphlib.php, its code is also pulled. So I'm assuming that means the file paths I am using are correct?

Comment: You mean the actual code is shown/downloaded? Do you have php installed? what is your server setup?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Do I just put phpinfo(); into my php file?

Comment: @Kypros yeah, the actual code from my php file is shown. I'm doing this all locally on my machine.  I haven't installed anything because I didn't know I had to?

Comment: Use `<?php phpinfo(); die; ?>` at the top of your `php` file and show us the output. You'll need a server (nginx/apache) plus php AT LEAST to run this code.